# bzr portable runtime

Tags: windows, portable, bazaar, bzr

I am looking for a portable (as in no-install needed, can-run-from pendrive) installation for Bzr with a graphical UI, a decentralized version control system.

I would like to recommend it to my students, who have no admin privileges on lab computers. Git is, IMHO, too unfriendly to use for second-year programmers, but I would be glad for any suggestions or ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread [Are there any plans for a portable (flash drive) version of Bazaar?](https://answers.launchpad.net/bzr/+question/91004) contains a description of installing Bazaar to a USB stick in a portable manner, as follows:

1. Install any flavor of [PortableApps](http://www.portableapps.com/) to your USB-stick.
2. Install the app "Command Prompt Portable" to your USB-stick.
3. Start the app and exit the command prompt again - this creates the necessary configuration file.
4. Install Bazaar on your machine, if not already done.
5. Copy the contents of your Bazaar installation to a directory "portable_bzr" on the USB-stick.
6. If you don't want to keep Bazaar installed locally, uninstall it.
7. Edit Command Prompt Portable's configuration file; you find it at:  $PortableAppsDirectory\CommandPromptPortable\data\Batch\commandprompt.bat
   Append the following two lines:
   `set BZR_HOME=%~d0\portable_bzr`
   `set path=%BZR_HOME%`
   and you're done.
   When launching Command Prompt Portable, you have all bzr commands available on any (Windows) machine.